# NullPointerException при попытке получения credentials.json

Tags: java, android

В Android Studio пытаюсь отправить запрос в Google-таблицу. Для этого использую пример кода из [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) в официальной документации Google Sheets API. Но есть проблема - в коде не получается найти файл credentials.json.

Имеется путь:

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
```

И два способа получения данного файла, оба из которых ничего не находят и в итоге, в in оказывается NULL:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
//InputStream in = GoogleSheets.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если все равно как - положите в пакет с классом и он найдется кодом, который вы привели в вопросе

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в том то и дело, что не найдется. В случае с getResouceAsStream будет NullPointerException, а при FileInputStream вылезает ошибка FileNotFoundException: /credentials.json (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете в случае андроида положить файл в папку `assets` и получить `InputStream` из него вот так:

```
public static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

public static InputStream getInputStreamFromAssets(Context context, String fileName) {
     return new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(fileName), "UTF-8");
}
```

далее где-то в коде где есть контекст:

```
InputStream in = getInputStreamFromAssets(context, CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH );
```

Если папки `assets` в проекте нет - надо создать её вручную. Для этого просто создайте папку с именем `assets` в `src/main`

Comment: А как мне достать context, если метод, в котором я хочу получить InputStream - это static метод? this я использовать не могу, получается, а какие еще варианты?

Comment: @МихаилЕршов, передайте контекст в метод через аргументы оного. Либо сделайте синглтон для контекста приложения (не активити, иначе утечка памяти будет). Лучше - через параметр передавать.